# Can not get jQuery functions working

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am trying to make a div that moves in and out of the page, however I can not make the jQuery function work.

It works perfectly here:

http://jsfiddle.net/WMGXr/1/

```
$('#toggle').toggle( 
function() {
    $('#popout').animate({ left: 0 }, 'slow', function() {
        $('#toggle').html('Close');
    });
}, 
function() {
    $('#popout').animate({ left: -40 }, 'slow', function() {
        $('#toggle').html('Show');
    });
}
);

<div id="popout">
<div id="toggle">Show</div>
<br style="clear: both" />
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>        
</ul>
</div>

#popout { position: fixed; height: 100px; width: 75px; border: 1px dotted gray;  background: darkblue; color: white; top:50px; left: -40px; }
#toggle { float: right; }
```

Here is how I tried implementing the function:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#toggle').toggle(
                function() {
                $('#popout').animate({ left: 0 }, 'slow', function() {
                                     $('#toggle').html('Close');
                                     });
                },
                function() {
                $('#popout').animate({ left: -40 }, 'slow', function() {
                                     $('#toggle').html('Show');
                                     });
                }
                );

</script>
</head>
```

However on my page it does not work. Why is this?

Comment: Read up on [jQuery document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). `$('#toggle')` is being processed before the element exists, thus nothing happens.

Comment: ^ that! Remember that jsFIDDLE adds a DOM ready handler automagically for you

Comment: @adeneo Took the next words out of my mouth. jsfiddle technically does `onload` by default, but same idea.

Comment: More about "document ready" here, it makes the enclosed functions wait for page load to fire: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: according to [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).`toggle` method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9

Comment: And as noted below, there is no `toggle` method that does what you want in that version of jQuery, it's been removed.

Comment: The issue is that you're trying to run your jQuery code BEFORE that element in the page has been loaded.  You can either move the script tag AFTER the relevant DOM element or use `$(document).ready()` to wait for the DOM to load before running your code.  This is a very common question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [toggle event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) has been removed after jquery version 1.9.

You can use the `click event` like

```
var left = -40;
$('#toggle').click(function () {
    left = left == 0 ? -40 : 0;
    html = 'Show';
    if (left == 0) {
        html = 'Close';
    }
    $('#popout ').animate({
        left: left
    }, 'slow', function () {
        $('#toggle ').html(html);
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/WMGXr/2292/)

```js
var left = -50;
$('#toggle').click(function () {
    left = left == 0 ? -50 : 0;
    html = 'Show';
    if (left == 0) {
        html = 'Close';
    }
    $('#popout ').animate({
        left: left
    }, 'slow', function () {
        $('#toggle ').html(html);
    });
});
```

```css
#popout {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 85px;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
  top: 50px;
  left: -50px;
}
#toggle {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="popout">
    <div id="toggle">Show</div>
    <br style="clear: both" />
    <ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this could be a comment than an answer. *just saying*

Comment: @CerlinBoss Could be, but not considerin the version is the main mistake in the question. So single line answerd it ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should be in the document ready function as given under

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#toggle').toggle(
                function() {
                $('#popout').animate({ left: 0 }, 'slow', function() {
                                     $('#toggle').html('Close');
                                     });
                },
                function() {
                $('#popout').animate({ left: -40 }, 'slow', function() {
                                     $('#toggle').html('Show');
                                     });
                }
                );

});
```

Comment: '.ready' has only one 'd' - The above code will not work until it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  //your toggle code here <br/>
});
```

Comment: You ought to add a little explanation to your answer.  "Try this" style answers are pretty unhelpful.